# Windows 10 Pro - Previous Version does not work on mapped network drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, shared-folders, previous-versions

I successfully configured a shared folder on a Windows 10 Pro machine (let's call it `host`) and I am able to access the folder on another Win 10 Pro machine (let's call it `client`) using `net use` command, providing the local user of the machine I am connecting to as credentials.

The shared folder has "Previous Versions" functionality working as intended, if I right-click on the local folder I can see and restore previous versions with no issues.

Unfortunately I am not able to do this on the `client` machine: if I right click on the same folder in my network mapped drive, I see "There are no previous versions available"

I think I am missing somethig but I did not find any help googling this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft documentation one requirements for Volume Shadow Copy via SMB is that both computers have to joined to the same domain:

> The application server and file server must be joined to the same Active Directory domain

[source: Protect Data on Remote SMB File Shares using VSS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj612865(v%3Dws.11)).

Comment: Now both `host` and `client` machines have joined the same domain, but this still doesn't work: I can see that `client` now displays "working on it..." when trying to open the previous versions dialog, then after 10 seconds if shows "There are no previous versions available"

Maybe it's because the `host` machine is a Win10 PRO instance and not a Windows Server?